# requiere once error php

Tags: php, apache

I have the following error

```
[error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../entidad/usuariosEntidad.php'
```

I have changed the requiere_once for include to get the code works but  I do not know why is that my file usuariosEntidad.php has a permision 777

the structure of the document is..
 -entidad/usuariosEntidad.php 
 -servicio/usuariosServicio.php
 -vista/util/indexUtil.php
  index.php
 So I'm trying to call UsuariosEntidad from usuariosServicio using

```
requiere_once '../entidad/usuariosEntidad.php';
```

Comment: does `../entidad/usuariosEntidad.php` exist relative to your current directory? So you should have to go back one folder, then go into entidad then there should be a file called `usuariosEntidad.php`

Comment: Also, if the file exists, double check permissions. The file needs to be able to be read by the apache user.

Comment: Is `../entidad/` outside the `open_basedir` setting of PHP?

Comment: @Steven yes it exists thats why when I use include instead it works.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn the permissions are -rwxrwxrwx. 1 andres andres 962 Aug 31 21:21 usuariosEntidad.php it does not belong to apache but the other files work with this user

Comment: @Barmar my open_basedir is commented on php I really do not know why I have to use include and not requiere_once to get the code works

Comment: The only difference between include and require is that include doesn't kill the script if the file can't be found, require does. If the file doesn't exist, you have to use include if you want to ignore the error.

Comment: There's lots of things to check for in the notes at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: @andresecuador heads up you have a typo errro too..its require_once  hope you know this

Comment: That's obviously just in his transcribing to SO, not the original. Otherwise he would have gotten a syntax error, not an error about not being able to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path is wrong...check with **[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)**

```
if(!@file_exists('../entidad/usuariosEntidad.php') ) {
    echo 'can not include';
} else {
   include('../entidad/usuariosEntidad.php');
}
```

you can also try giving absolute path

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/entidad/usuariosEntidad.php');
```

Comment: I do not think the path is the problem because when I use include it works

Comment: Are you sure it works?  Just because you're not getting an error doesn't mean it works -- see my comment above.

Comment: @Barmar yes it gives an Warning on the /var/log/httpd/error_log: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/entidad/usuariosEntidad.php'

Comment: @andresecuador i agree with barmar just because your include does't give error it is getting included..try to include a dummy file with echo and exit..

Comment: yes @Sibu it does not found the file with your code but I think my reference to de file is ok :( i edited the question with the structure of my page

Comment: @Barmar the output is can not include

Comment: @andresecuador so the path you have given does not exists..use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with above code..and paste output and also use ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

If the `entdadad` directory is in the same directory as `index.php`, as shown above, then you don't need `../` at the beginning of the `require_once`. It should be:

```
require_once 'entidad/usuariosEntidad.php';
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, I'm calling usuariosEntidad.php from -servicio/usuariosServicio.php so I need the ../